# Automate using SQL Express to export to Excel (not CSV)

Tags: export-to-excel, sql-server-2012-express

I need to export about 20 different query results into one Excel file in seperate tabs.

I know we can use SSIS pacakage but as I am using express addition it will not let me save it. As I will be running this checks every fortnight I am looking for some automattion.

Any suggessions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a tool or for a method ?

I know 2 tools that can do this :
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/ReportManager.aspx
http://www.hybing.com/report-genie.html

Report genie is free for personal use and $25 for business.

R-Tag is $25, but is giving 1 free license per company (can be requested from here: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/FreeCrystalReportsViewer.aspx)

R-Tag has also a scheduler (not included in the free license)

Comment: Thanks Lan, I was looking for method but this free tools does help. Cheers